# Autodesk Forge Viewer DWF load - Error while processing SVF

Tags: autodesk-forge

From yesterday, loading a DWF file on the a Autodesk Forge Viewer, it gave this error:

Error while processing SVF: {"url":"http://localhost/ForgeOfflineSimple/dwf/AA5A000151.dwf","exception":"TypeError: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope': Failed to read the 'transfer' property from 'StructuredSerializeOptions': The object must have a callable @@iterator property.","stack":"TypeError: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope': Failed to read the 'transfer' property from 'StructuredSerializeOptions': The object must have a callable @@iterator property.\n    at DwfParserEmscripten.addImage (blob:http://localhost/dc821203-92f7-4e66-aeaf-4c1e01d3fb33:17:309048)\n    at methodCaller_bool_$unsigned$long_unsigned$long_std$$wstring_std$$wstring$ (eval at _i (blob:http://localhost/dc821203-92f7-4e66-aeaf-4c1e01d3fb33:17:217386), :8:26)\n    at Hi (blob:http://localhost/dc821203-92f7-4e66-aeaf-4c1e01d3fb33:17:225857)\n    at wasm://wasm/0286874a:wasm-function[33417]:0x892d89\n    at wasm://wasm/0286874a:wasm-function[33414]:0x892bf8\n    at wasm://wasm/0286874a:wasm-function[33407]:0x8929d3\n    at wasm://wasm/0286874a:wasm-function[33405]:0x8928bf\n    at wasm://wasm/0286874a:wasm-function[32499]:0x871817\n    at wasm://wasm/0286874a:wasm-function[32498]:0x871565\n    at wasm://wasm/0286874a:wasm-function[32995]:0x889122"}

Is there something change on the viewer?
How can I solved this problem?

UPDATE:
I've seen that the problem is appear only on google chrome or Edge browser.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved with Viewer SDK V7.93 and will bring texture loading back into Chrome.